# Random Sentence generator in HTML / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, random, generator, phrase

I'm looking to build a simple mini site with a random sentence generator. That when the visitor clicks a button the site display a random phrase that is taken from a database of phrases.

And if its possible a second mini site that lets the users add their own phrases for the database that is going to be used for the first mini-site.

I'm still new in hand-coding things, but I'm working hard on it

Something like this:
First site:  [First site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJFl8.png)
Second site: [Second site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6bb6.png)

Comment: Cool. Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you know to develop a website? Did you build anything? Know HTML/JavaScript/php anything?

Comment: @MorHaviv Yes, I know HTML, Css and some JavaScript.
Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough jaja my question and the thing that I don't know how to do is how I make a button call a phrase from the database and display it on the minisite.
And how to add a phrase to a database.
So I think my problem are databases, how to call things from them and how to add things to them

Comment: Ok give me one moment I will make you an example

Comment: Sorry I'm still working on it. It will take me 2 more minutes

Comment: @MorHaviv Of course! take the time you need jaja and thank you!

Comment: Just posted an answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using php and javascript I created 2 files.

- call.php **- Retrieves a sentence from a database and prints one of them (Random)**
- index.html **- A page with a button that runs a function which retrieves a sentence from call.php**

**call.php:**

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost"; //Host address (most likely localhost)
$db_name = "DATABASE_NAME"; //Name of Database
$db_user = "DATABASE_USERNAME"; //Name of database user
$db_pass = "DATABASE_PASSWORD"; //Password for database user
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sentence
                FROM `table_sentences`
                "); //gets all the values in the column "sentence" from the table `table_sentences`
$stmt->execute(); //Execute the query
$stmt->bind_result($sentence); //Bind the results into array
$array = array(); 
while ($stmt->fetch()){
    array_push($array,$sentence); //enter each sentence, in to the array ($array)
}
$stmt->close(); //Close the connection

$rand = array_rand($array, 1); //Random one value from the array

echo $rand[0]; //Echo the value
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getSentence() { //defines a function named getSentence
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //creating a new request
    xhr.open("get", "call.php", true); //setting the file to get the data from
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var response = xhr.responseText; //Save the sentence into a var
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = response; //Set where the sentence should display
    }
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'); //Prevent caching
    xhr.send(null); //Submit the request
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="text"></p>
<button onClick="getSentence()">Get Sentence</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, when you said " gets all the sentences in a database " from where is getting all this sentences?
For this to work if I understand your php an existing database with sentences is needed and the code select a random one from the column "table_sentences" isn't? and thats the one that will be displayed when the button is clicked isn't? and the <p> with the id "text" is where the sentences will appear.
I think I'm understanding all this. I appreciate that you took the time to respond.
Just one more question it's possible to add more sentences to the database from a "textarea" and a button ?

Comment: @MvM You need an existing database with a list of sentences. If you want to add new sentences to the database, that's a total different question. You can search up online: "How to insert data into mysql database" **OR** you can create a question in stack overflow..

Comment: Right! then I will work with a existing database first until i get this done and then ask for the other question. Good day!

Comment: @MvM Have a great day! Glad I helped!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about data bases, but using js and a bit of jQuery, here's what you could do:

**1.** Create an array with all the phrases:

```
var phrases = [
["Phrase 1"],
["Phrase 2"],
["Phrase 3"]
];
```

**2.** Create a function that randomizes the phrases (I use jQuery to get the id of the text where the phrase is displayed, but you could use `getElementById` if you wanted):

```
var randPhraseNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length);
$("#phraseText").text(phrases[randPhraseNum]);
```

**3.** Use the `push()` method to add new phrases to your array:

```
phrases.push("New Phrase");
```

I know that this isn't exactly what you asked for but I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will try this on Jsfiddle